# instance_of? returning unexpected result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an observer following two models:

```
class MyObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :my_first_model, :my_second_model

  def after_create(record)
    x = if record.instance_of?(MyFirstModel)
      # x is set to one thing
    elsif record.instance_of?(MySecondModel)
      # x is set to another thing
    end

    # use x in a common way
  end
end
```

As you can see, I'm setting `x` to something different depending on the model whose creation is being observed.

I'm getting unexpected results using `instance_of?` and `kind_of?`. For instance, I can do `Rails.logger.debug record.class.name` and see `MyFirstModel` but `record.instance_of?(MyFirstModel)` returns false.

Has anyone come across this before? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1.

In the mean time, I'm going to resort to `record.class.name.inquiry.MyFirstModel?` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` statement for this.

```
def after_create(record)
  x = case record
    when MyFirstModel
      # x is set to one thing
    when MySecondModel
      # x is set to another thing
    else ; return false
  end

  # use x in a common way
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @gg_s. I didn't know that you could use a class name in a case statement like that so something new learned. Sadly, it didn't solve the problem and `record` isn't being identified correctly.